# show difference in 2 times

Tags: javascript, date, react-native, format, momentjs

[image] Its giving me like this instead of showing how many hours its showing "in hrs" but the real issue is even though the date is todays and time should show in minutes its giving me in hours.. 
I have to display time based on condition that if the order has been placed few minutes earlier it should show `"1 min"`, if few hours ago then `"18 hr"` if it is not of the present date it should show date in the format `"29/06/18"`. using `moment.js` any help is appreciated.

This is my code:

export class Notifications extends PureComponent {

```
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            notificationsData: null,
            isLoading: true
        };
    }
componentDidMount() {
    if (notifications) {
        this.setState({
            notificationsData: notifications.data,
            isLoading: false
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    }
}

renderIconBadge(icon) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.iconBagdeContainer}>
            <Icon name={icon} size={scale(16)} />
        </View>
    );
}

  getDateFormatted(dateTime) {

  var date = moment(dateTime, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").isValid() ? 
  moment(dateTime, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm") 
  : moment(new Date(dateTime), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
  var diff = date.fromNow();

  if (diff.indexOf("minute") > -1) {
    return diff.substring(0, 2).trim() + " mins";
  } else if (diff.indexOf("hour") > -1) {
     //If it's yesterday
     if(date.day() != moment().day()){
         return date.format("DD/MM/YYYY"); 
     } 
    return diff.substring(0, 2).trim() + " hrs";
  } else {
    return date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  }
}

renderNotificationCard = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <Card style={styles.notificationCardContainer}>
            <View
                style={{
                    flexDirection: "row"
                }}
            >
                {/* <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}> */}
                {this.renderIconBadge(item.icon)}
                <View
                    style={{
                        marginLeft: scale(12)
                    }}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={styles.location}
                        numberOfLines={3}
                        ellipsizeMode="tail"
                    >
                        {item.location}
                    </Text>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                        <ClickView onPress={() => {}}>
                            <Text style={styles.viewBooking}>
                                View Booking
                            </Text>
                        </ClickView>
                        <Text style={styles.dateFormat}>
                            {this.getDateFormatted(item.dateTime)}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                {/* </View> */}
            </View>
        </Card>
    );
};

renderNotificationList() {
    const { notificationsData } = this.state;
    return (
        <View style={{ marginTop: scale(10), marginBottom: scale(100) }}>
            {notificationsData.notification.length !== 0 ? (
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.notificationsData.notification}
                    renderItem={this.renderNotificationCard}
                />
            ) : (
                <View
                    style={{
                        marginTop: scale(100),

                        alignItems: "center"
                    }}
                >
                    <Image source={Images.noTaskImg} />
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            marginTop: scale(20),
                            fontSize: scale(18),
                            fontWeight: "600",
                            color: Colors.body
                        }}
                    >
                        No Notifications found.
                    </Text>
                </View>
            )}
        </View>
    );
}

render() {
    const { isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
        <ThemeView
            theme="dark"
            style={styles.mainContainer}
            rightButton="close"
            onRightButtonPress={() => {
                this.props.navigation.goBack();
            }}
        >
            {isLoading ? (
                <ProgressBar />
            ) : (
                <View>
                    <View
                        style={{ marginTop: scale(Metrics.headerHeight) }}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.newTasks}>New Tasks</Text>
                        {this.renderNotificationList()}
                    </View>
                </View>
            )}
        </ThemeView>
    );
}
```

}

JSON data format is like this

```
{
    id: "1",
    icon: "water",
    location:
        "Your booking water",
    dateTime: "2018-06-12T20:20:52.123Z"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually to check the difference you can use [**fromNow()**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) and according to the result, you can return your custom string.

This is how should be your function:

```
var getDateFormatted = function(dateTime) {

  var date = moment(dateTime, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").isValid() ? 
  moment(dateTime, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm") 
  : moment(new Date(dateTime), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
  var diff = date.fromNow();

  if (diff.indexOf("minute") > -1) {
    return diff.substring(0, 2).trim() + " mins";
  } else if (diff.indexOf("hour") > -1) {
     //If it's yesterday
     if(date.day() != moment().day()){
         return date.format("DD/MM/YYYY"); 
     } 
    return diff.substring(0, 2).trim() + " hrs";
  } else {
    return date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  }
}
```

```js
var getDateFormatted = function(dateTime) {

  var date = moment(dateTime, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").isValid() ?
    moment(dateTime, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm") :
    moment(new Date(dateTime), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
  var diff = date.fromNow();

  if (diff.indexOf("minutes") > -1) {
    return diff.substring(0, 2).trim() + " mins";
  } else if (diff.indexOf("hour") > -1) {
    if (date.day() != moment().day()) {
      return date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    }
    return diff.substring(0, 2).trim() + " hrs";
  } else {
    return date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  }
}

var data = {
  id: "1",
  icon: "water",
  location: "Your booking water",
  dateTime: "2018-06-12T20:20:52.123Z"
};

console.log(getDateFormatted("28/06/2018 23:00"));
console.log(getDateFormatted("29/06/2018 11:50"));
console.log(getDateFormatted("28/06/2018 01:00"));
console.log(getDateFormatted(data.dateTime));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.....But i don't want to display hours ago or days ago.

Comment: thanks a lot what if i get the date in this format "2018-06-12T20:20:52.123Z"

Comment: how to convert "2018-06-12T20:20:52.123Z" into "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm" format.

Comment: @abhijith You can just wrap it in `new Date(data.dateTime)` before passing it, take a look at the example in my snippet.

Comment: @abhijith I edited the solution, so it constructs the date correctly from the input.

Comment: You need to test if the "time ago" is larger than the time that has elapsed since the start of today: "*if it is not of the present date it should show date*", not just if the returned string has minutes or hours.

Comment: @RobG Ah ok Thank you, I got it, edited the answer with that condition.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but its printing invalid date... Please help guys

Comment: @abhijith Have you checked my edited snippet? and code?

Comment: ya i did check but still its printing invalid date.. i dont know why

Comment: @abhijith Please post a [**fiddle**](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with your code, so I can check it and tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: its in react native

Comment: @abhijith You are calling it with the wrong date in `{this.getDateFormatted(item.date)}` it should be `{this.getDateFormatted(item.dateTime)}`, because in your JSON it's `dateTime`.

Comment: else condition is working fine but the other 2 conditions doesn't seem to be working please help

Comment: The validation step seems pointless. The tested format ("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm") doesn't match the format in the OP's JSON and both paths of the `? :` condition use the same (non–matching) format to validate against. The OP date string is consistent with ISO 8601 which moment.js will parse by default.

Comment: How is it pointless? while it works as you see in the snippet?! @abhijith can you please provide more details? I can't understand your problem?

Comment: i have added the image of the result please refer it

Comment: @abhijith Please post your code in a [**jsfiddle**](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)  and share it here, so I can check it and tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: Please make the effort to build a complete, running codePen or fiddle? Go to codePen and configure it so it reads react code. The shared jsfiddle isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to test if the date is "today" and if not, return a date string in the required format. Otherwise, return the time ago in the required format.

Since you want something different to the default "from now" returned by moment.js and it's not difficult to write your own, you might as well do that. See below.

#### Edit

The above function expects to get a Date object, so if your source JSON is:

```
'{"id":"1","icon":"water","location":"Your booking water","dateTime":"2018-06-12T20:20:52.123Z"}'
```

then you need to get the *dateTime* property and turn it into a Date. Note that the supplied string will be parsed as UTC (given the Z timezone identifier) but the results of the function will be based on the host timezone offset.

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var d = new Date();
  var diff = d - date;

  // If yesterday, return a formatted date
  if (d.getDate() != date.getDate()) {
    return moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  }

  // If diff less than an hour ago, return minutes
  if (diff < 3.6e6) {
    return (diff/6e4 | 0) + ' min';
  }

  // Otherwise, return hours
  return (diff/3.6e6 | 0) + ' hr';
}

// Some test dates
var a = new Date();
// 3 minutes ago
var b = new Date(a.setMinutes(a.getMinutes() - 3));
// 1 hour and 3 minutes ago
var c = new Date(a.setHours(a.getHours() - 1));
// 2 hour and 3 minutes ago
var d = new Date(a.setHours(a.getHours() - 1));
// 1 day, 2 hour and 3 minutes ago
a.setDate(a.getDate() - 1);

[b,c,d,a].forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(`${moment(d).format('DD/MM/YY HH:mm')} => ${formatDate(d)}`);
});

// Using sample JSON:
var jsonTxt = '{"id":"1", "icon":"water", "location":"Your booking water", "dateTime":"2018-06-12T20:20:52.123Z"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonTxt);

// Without moment.js
console.log(formatDate(new Date(obj.dateTime)));

// With moment.js
console.log(formatDate(moment(obj.dateTime).toDate()));

// Make dateTime 3 minutes ago
var s = b.toISOString(); // UTC 3 mins ago
obj.dateTime = s;
console.log(`${s} => ${formatDate(new Date(obj.dateTime))}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

NB. The usual caveat applies to using the built-in parser: if you can guarantee that the string will strictly comply with the format in ECMA-262 with a timezone (e.g. "Z" or ±HH:mm) then it's fairly safe to use. Otherwise, use the moment parser.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but if i use date.getDate() it gives me an error saying undefined is not a function. This is exactly what i need.. Please help

Comment: You need to pass a Date to the function, so something like: `formatDate(new Date(obj.dateTime))` which is equivalent to `formatDate(new Date("2018-06-12T20:20:52.123Z"))`. Make sure the format is correct though, any deviation from the version of ISO 8601 in ECMA-262 will likely give different results in different browsers.

Comment: I have edited the code above where do i add this function please help me.. I'm new to this.

Comment: @abhijith—change `this.getDateFormatted` to `this.formatDate` since that's the name of your function (or change the name of the function to *getDateFormatted*).

Comment: Still getting the same error... by the way what is the use of this- (diff/6e4 | 0)

Comment: @abhijith— `diff / 6e4` divides the value of *diff* by 60,000 (i.e. 6x10^4, which is the number of milliseconds in one minute), `| 0` truncates any decimal part (just a shorter way of writing `parseInt(diff / 60000)`.

Comment: ya ya i got it.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [fromNow()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) of **momentjs**. It will give you desired output.

```js
var duration = moment("29/06/18", "DD/MM/YYYY").fromNow(); // in moment("pass your timestamp/valid date")

console.log(duration);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, that is the function to achieve that. Just a small note for @abhijith you need convert the "29/06/18" into a date ``var d = new Date("29/06/18");`` that should do.
and then ``var duration = moment(d).fromNow();``

Comment: @AdrianGrzywaczewski **NO**. It will not work. Check my answer for how to pass date in moment().

Comment: appreciate your help guys... But i do not want to hard code today's date is there any work around for that

Comment: @abhijith Problem is that you don’t have provided enough information in your question. Add some examples of input dates so that I can give you solution accordingly

Comment: @VicJordan i have edited the question please refer it.

Comment: As you can see the third condition satisfies so it should show 12/06/2018